# Laravel: Creating a common function for all models

Tags: laravel, methods, module, repeat

In my laravel(7.x) application, I have a common functionality to show the count of all the active and inactive records in all the modules. Therefore, I am obligated to repeat the same functionality on every module.

For example: `Device, DeviceType, DeviceCompany, etc` models have a same method called `_getTotal` and everywhere that `_getTotal` method is doing the same work.

Device.php

```php
class Device extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'devices';

    ...

    public function _getTotal($status = \Common::STATUS_ACTIVE)
    {
        return self::where([
            'status' => $status
        ])->count() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

DeviceType.php

```php
class DeviceType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'device_types';

    ...

    public function _getTotal($status = \Common::STATUS_ACTIVE)
    {
        return self::where([
            'status' => $status
        ])->count() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

I tried to put this method in the `Base Model` but I think may not be a good practice. Am I right..?
Is there any way to make this method `_getTotal` a common method for all the modules..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could move this method to a trait and include the trait instead to all classes that need this method.

```
trait DeviceStatusTotal
{
    public function _getTotal($status = \Common::STATUS_ACTIVE)
    {
        return self::where([
            'status' => $status
        ])->count() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

**DeviceType.php**

```
class DeviceType extends Model
{
    use DeviceStatusTotal;

    protected $table = 'device_types';

    // ...
}
```

Comment: where should this trait be placed? In a "Traits" folder inside "app"?

Comment: Anywhere you like. They don't have to be in a specific namespace. I like to keep traits together with the classes they're for, for example traits for models will reside in `App\Models\Concerns` and traits for requests in `App\Requests\Concerns`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can create a classe extending Model default class and your models extends from this custom class (that haves your custom function)

Comment: Coming from Codeigniter 3, this is the way I did it so far (with a core base model) or used a library. Didn't find any other way to do it yet in Laravel.

Comment: The issue with this is, if you create a class inheriting from any of the basic Laravel classes that themselves inherit from Model, like Pivot or Authenticatable, your classes won't inherit from your own BaseModel which leads to inconsistency. You'll eventually need to use a trait somehow.

Anyone inheriting from a BaseModel, though, should also publish and edit artisan stubs ( https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#stub-customization ) so their generated models inherit from the BaseModel as well by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel Global scopes:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes

Another why use traits and use in the models and make the method to local scope as:

```
public function scopePopular($query) {
    return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
}
```